# Apache / Gunicorn and Django Issue

Tags: django, apache, gunicorn

I have an application that runs using

```
client --> apache --> gunicorn --> wsgi --> django
```

When I run my code it starts to run and then I receive the following within the apache logs,

```
(20014)Internal error: proxy: error reading status line from remote server 127.0.0.1
proxy: Error reading from remote server returned by /app/view
```

No exceptions show in the code. However if I run the code without the gunicord/proxy layer it works. Also this only affects some requests.

Heres is my apache conf.d file.

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.6.1:443>

        ServerName app.domain.net

        Alias /static /production/pythonenv/app/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/static/
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/app-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/app-access.log common

        LogLevel warn

        RewriteEngine On
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
        RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:9008/$1 [P]
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9008/

        SetEnv force-proxy-request-1.0 1 
        SetEnv proxy-nokeepalive 1
        RequestHeader unset Expect early

        ErrorLog logs/app-ssl-error.log
        CustomLog logs/app-ssl-access.log common
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /opt/ssl/crt/cert.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /opt/ssl/crt/key.key
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: How are your starting gunicorn/Django?

Comment: Possibly the request took more than the timeout value for individual requests that gunicorn applies and the gunicorn worker process was killed resulting in the proxy connection being dropped and thus no status line being sent for the response.

Comment: This comment helped me fix the issue.